# SQL - Update String in Colum with regex

Tags: sql, oracle

Using SQL, I am trying to update substring in a column with regexp.

That's my goal :

- I have HTML content in my column :
  example :

  ```
  <a href="http://blabla.fr/blibli">Link1</a>
  ```

or an other content with multiple links:

```
  <p>BlaBlaBla</p>
  <a href="http://blabla.fr/blibli">Link1</a>
  <a href="http://blabla.fr/">Link2</a>
  <a href="http://blabla.fr/test">Link3 </a>
```

(This example represente an entire string, not many result of select )
 - I want to remove 'http://' in urls which not contains 'blibli'

So I did this query

```
 UPDATE my_table SET my_col = replace(my_col,'http://','') where not regexp_like(my_col,'http://^((?blibli).)*$')
```

But this work only if the column contains at least one link like my first example.
If the column contains many link, it will update nothing due to the conditions. (Maybe doing this with many step? )
I tried to have a look to REGEXP_SUBSTR but i think i can't achieve this with it too.
The desired result for the second example is :

```
<p>BlaBlaBla</p>
<a href="http://blabla.fr/blibli">Link1</a>
<a href="blabla.fr/">Link2</a>
<a href="blabla.fr/test">Link3 </a>
```

Thanks for any advice you can give me

Comment: Just to be clear, your second example is a column value - i.e. a single string - not values from four rows in your table? Also is `blibli` always going to be the last part of the URL, or can it be in the middle, or always a level in a path at least (i.e. is it always `.../blibli"` or `.../blibli/...`) ?

Comment: Yes sorry, all the values in the second example are contains in a single string, and "blibli" can be anywhere. I edited my post ;) . Thanks for this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Trung's approach, but capturing both (either) matched group:

```
update my_table set my_col = regexp_replace(my_col,
  'href="(http://[^"]*blibli[^"]*)"|href="http://([^"]*)"', 'href="\1\2"')
```

optionally with a `where` clause to avoid updating rows that don't have an `href`, say.

Quick demo of how sample values (supplied in a CTE) are translated:

```
with my_table (id, my_col) as (
  select 1, '<a href="http://blabla.fr/blibli">Link1</a>' from dual
  union all select 2, '<a href="http://blabla.fr/blibli/abc">Link1</a>' from dual
  union all select 3, '<a href="http://blabla.fr/xbliblix">Link1</a>' from dual
  union all select 4, '<a href="http://blabla.fr/test">Link1</a>' from dual
  union all select 5, '<p>BlaBlaBla</p>
<a href="http://blabla.fr/blibli">Link1</a>
<a href="http://blabla.fr/">Link2</a>
<a href="http://blabla.fr/test">Link3 </a>' from dual
)
select id, my_col, regexp_replace(my_col,
    'href="(http://[^"]*blibli[^"]*)"|href="http://([^"]*)"',
    'href="\1\2"') as result
from my_table;

        ID MY_COL                                           RESULT                                          
---------- ------------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------
         1 <a href="http://blabla.fr/blibli">Link1</a>      <a href="http://blabla.fr/blibli">Link1</a>     
         2 <a href="http://blabla.fr/blibli/abc">Link1</a>  <a href="http://blabla.fr/blibli/abc">Link1</a> 
         3 <a href="http://blabla.fr/xbliblix">Link1</a>    <a href="http://blabla.fr/xbliblix">Link1</a>   
         4 <a href="http://blabla.fr/test">Link1</a>        <a href="blabla.fr/test">Link1</a>              
         5 <p>BlaBlaBla</p>                                 <p>BlaBlaBla</p>                                
           <a href="http://blabla.fr/blibli">Link1</a>      <a href="http://blabla.fr/blibli">Link1</a>     
           <a href="http://blabla.fr/">Link2</a>            <a href="blabla.fr/">Link2</a>                  
           <a href="http://blabla.fr/test">Link3 </a>       <a href="blabla.fr/test">Link3 </a>
```

Comment: Thanks for all this explaination ;-) and good point about matching both group ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You could use REGEXP_REPLACE, with grouping

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_col= REGEXP_REPLACE(my_col, 'href="(http://.*blibli[^"]*)|href="http://([^"])', 'href="\1')
```

You could check the sample at this link http://rextester.com/HEMG60862

Comment: Thanks for this tip. It work ;-). @Alex Poole mentionned a good point about matching both group. Regex_replace was the good way

Answer (score 1):

You said "I want to remove 'http://' in urls which not contains 'blibli'"

Why do not you use simple regex like that?

```
 UPDATE my_table SET my_col= replace(my_col,'http://','') where not regexp_like(my_col,'*blibli*')
```

Comment: It looks like the second example is a single string column value that has three URLs in it, and only two of them should be touched. Not entirely clear though.